# Do Linux system calls and API depend on Linux distributions?

Tags: linux

Do

- Linux system calls
- Linux API

depend on

- Linux distributions (e.g. Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu, Arch, Gentoo, ...), and/or
- Linux kernel?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question about Linux System calls, you need to read `man syscalls`.

So yes, with different distributions, Linux kernel will change, hence the available system calls.

What do you mean by Linux API?

- Linux Kernel's internal API
- or the C ABI

Comment: (1) "with different distributions, Linux kernel will change". I am considering same kernel for all distributions. What is your answer then? (2) Linux API is an OS API library, built upon OS system calls.

Answer (score 2):

Answer depends on the fact that is it a POSIX compliant call and if you are using a POSIX compliant system.

If your are using a POSIX call them most the system you have mentioned will support and work pretty much in the same way, since its a well defined standard that they follow them strictly.

There exists many system calls that are specific to certain systems, if you use such system calls or API then you your code is at risk since there is a good chance that it may or may not be available on the other systems.

More on [POSIX here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part, the answer is mixture of yes and no, the yes part, all distributions of Linux, their core, the kernel comes from the main [repository](http://kernel.org) tree.

The no part, is that there is huge differences between Kernel 2.x, Kernel 3.x, likewise, Kernel 4.x, so the underlying implementation of the API governing aspects of the system, such as device drivers, for example, is different. For example, kernel module that is dependent on Kernel v3.x implementation, will not work under Kernel v2.x.

That is nonetheless to say, differing implementations can be backported to the older versions of the Kernel.

However, the system calls are relatively static and have not changed much. (see [SysCalls](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/))

Distributions, on the other hand, encompasses the Kernel and all libraries, notably GNU C library, which would have been recompiled as updates are made where applicable.

Provided the API behind those runtime libraries have not changed, then code that targets a version of library can be recompiled against a newer version of them runtime libraries.